# Magento 2: How to submit custom html content from ui_form to controller?

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform, admin-controller, ui-form

I am developing a module using ui_form. I have developed ui_form and on submit it post all fields except custom html fields.

For example:

```
<container name="pl_labelposition" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label Position</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\ProductLabel\Edit\LabelPosition</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
```

I also use conditions  of sales rules:

```
        <container name="conditions_apply_to" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>

            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
```

Could you help me to resolve this problem? I am not able to submit such fields to controller. How can i use in controller?

Help will be appreciated

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your block create

```
protected $_template = 'Company_Module::labelposition.phtml';
```

now, make **`labelposition.phtml`** and add your html field with **attribute** **`data-form-part="formname"`**.

Here the **`formname`** must be **name of your uiform** like **`<uiComponent name="product_form"/>`**.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" data-form-part="product_form" name="test" value="Hello World">
```

You will get the value of this field.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It works. I was just missing data-form-part attribute.

Comment: great to know that it helped you. your welcome

Comment: With e.g `<input type="checkbox" data-form-part="product_form" name="test[]" value="Hello World"> <input type="checkbox" data-form-part="product_form" name="test[]" value="Hello World Two">`. it not submit true.

Comment: nice answer. worked perfectly.

Comment: glad to know it...

Comment: how to add require property on field ?

Comment: you save my days, it works, thank you very much